# DBFS : How to get Last access time of DBFS file in Datarbricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

Is it possible to get the time when file was opened last time as like `ls -ltu` list all the files, showing and sorting by access time in Unix by using of `dbutils`. This we required to get the stat about ADLS file in Databricks note.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `ls -ltu` option while using Databricks Utilities (DBUtils).

[image]

**Usage:** `dbuitls.fs.ls` The sequence returned by the ls command contains the following attributes:

[image]

Use the **Hadoop filesystem API** to get the last access time for DBFS filesytem in Azure Databricks.

This code uses the Hadoop filesystem’s listStatus method to sort the DBFS files based on the modification time.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val path = new Path("/mnt/abc")
val fs = path.getFileSystem(spark.sessionState.newHadoopConf)
val inodes = fs.listStatus(path).sortBy(_.getModificationTime)
inodes.filter(_.getModificationTime > 0).map(t => (t.getPath, t.getModificationTime, t.getLen)).foreach(println)
```

**Example1:** stat about ADLS file in Databricks notebook

[image]

**Example2:** stat about DBFS file in Databricks notebook

[image]